# Seeding Arrays With Randomly Generated Numbers and Sorting

Tags: c

I'm trying to practice my C by creating arrays of equal size (determined by the user's input) and populating them with random numbers. I'm running into some issues. First, my creation and allocation of the arrays:

```
    srandom((int)time(NULL)); /* initialize random seed for later use*/

    unsigned long arraySize = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0); 

    int *originalArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
    int *ascendingOrderArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
    int *descendingOrderArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
```

Next, the loop wherein I populate the arrays with random numbers:

```
    int i = 0;
    int randInt;
    /* Seed each array with identical randomly generated numbers */
    while(i++ < arraySize){
        randInt = (int)random()%100;
        *originalArray++ = randInt;
        printf("original array assign: %d\n", originalArray);
        *ascendingOrderArray++ = originalArray;
        printf("ascending array assign: %d\n", ascendingOrderArray);
        *descendingOrderArray++ = originalArray;
        printf("descending array assign: %d\n", descendingOrderArray);

    }
```

Here, things get weird. I'm expecting each array to have the same number as that assigned to originalArray for each index. Yet the output I get from the `printf` statement does not reflect that. Moreover, the numbers are gigantic but they all have a similar base, starting with a 2 and extending for many digits. Should that be happening?

Finally, when I'm done with everything and do a little inconsequential printing and formatting, I try to free my arrays:

```
free(originalArray);
originalArray = NULL;
free(ascendingOrderArray);
ascendingOrderArray = NULL;
free(descendingOrderArray);
descendingOrderArray = NULL;
return 0;
```

But I'm getting a `pointer being freed was not allocated` error.

I'm sure I'm screwing up on multiple levels here, but the question is: where?

Comment: You have type errors all over the place. Are you just ignoring your compiler's warning messages?

Comment: The line `*ascendingOrderArray++ = originalArray;` should be giving you a compiler warning because you are assigning a pointer to an integer.  Get the code to compile cleanly with no warnings, then come back and ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same fundamental problem with all 3 arrays, but let's look at just one.  Here you allocate it:

`int *originalArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));`

So the variable `originalArray` points to the block of allocated memory.  Then you start using it to assign to the array:

`*originalArray++ = randInt;`

This is bad.  You just incremented `originalArray`, and now have no pointer to the beginning of the memory block.  What you should do is

`originalArray[i] = randInt;`
`printf("original array assign: %d\n", originalArray[i]);`

This way you're using the index `i` to say where in the array the number should go, and `originalArray` itself is still the pointer to the block of allocated memory, i.e. the beginning of your array.

Since `originalArray` is unchanged through all of this, when you

`free(originalArray);`

then `originalArray` is still the value that was returned from `malloc`, which is what `free` wants to get back.

Summary: you should always free the exact pointer that malloc returns, and you should never discard/change the value of that pointer.